# Links on mobile not working after adding auto ads

Tags: javascript, html, xml, mobile, adsense

I'm using Blogger's Soho template
After adding adsense's auto ad code in the , the links on my blog can't seem to work properly. It doesn't respond on the 1st click, you need to click it multiple times to trigger it. Sometimes it will work right after I refresh the page. This is only happening on mobile devices and the problem is gone once I remove the auto ad code.

From the adsense/blogger help forum, this seems to be a problem with other templates like Contempo and Notable too but there isn't any solution available.

The responsive ad on the sticky header also covered the content when scrolling but it's not a problem anymore after adding this css:

```
.centered-top-container.sticky {
    position: inherit !important;
}
```

Still don't know what to do with the links tho...
I've temporary removed the auto ad code for now since my readers are annoyed that they can't click on the links.

And i'm not familiar with html/css at all...so I'm not sure which part of the blog's html I should share?
I didn't make any changes to the default soho template.

Comment: Hi, I'm going completely mad with the same error on a Wordpress theme (SmartMag)... did you find out the reason?

Answer (score 1):

check your css body and remove width and height value 100% that will solve problem